# Kruskal-Katona type question for union-closed families of sets

Tags: co.combinatorics

Question: Let $n,k$ be two positive integers with $n \geq k$. Let $\mathcal{F}$ be a family of $C(n,k)$ sets, each of size $k$, and let $\langle\mathcal{F}\rangle$ denote the union-closed family generated by $\mathcal{F}$, i.e.: $\langle\mathcal{F}\rangle$ consists of all those sets which can be expressed as a union of members of $\mathcal{F}$.

> Must it be the case that
> \begin{equation}
> |\langle\mathcal{F}\rangle| \geq \sum_{j=k}^{n} C(n,j),
> \end{equation}
> with equality if and only if $\mathcal{F}$ consists of all $k$-element subsets of an $n$-set ?

Let $w(\mathcal G)$ denote the average size of the members of a family $\mathcal G$.

It is easy to see that if the inequality holds (whatever about uniqueness), then it implies that, for any union-closed family $\mathcal{G}$ and non-negative integer $m$,
$$|\mathcal{G}| \geq 2^{m}\implies w(\mathcal{G})\ge m/2.$$
This is, in turn, a special case of a result of Reimer [1] that, for any union-closed family $\mathcal{G}$ one has
$$w(\mathcal{G}) \geq \frac{1}{2} \log_{2} |\mathcal{G}|.$$
Indeed I had conjectured the same result and in thinking about it was led to the above question, before I recently became aware of Reimer's proof, which is a beautiful piece of work !

One can obviously try to generalise my question to an arbitrary number of generating $k$-sets, perhaps along the lines of the Kruskal-Katona theorem for shadows ?

[1] *Reimer, David*, [**An average set size theorem**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1017/S0963548302005230), Comb. Probab. Comput. 12, No. 1, 89-93 (2003). [ZBL1013.05083](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1013.05083).

Comment: You might make it clear that union F is potentially greater than n.
Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.09.16

Comment: What about the underlying set being of size C(n,k), and each member of F is that set minus a singleton?  I then get < F > having one set more than F.  Or is there something I am missing?  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.09.16

Comment: I apologize for not meeting all of the problem requirements, especially the condition of each set being of size k.  Nevertheless, I have a feeling that some example similar to the above is possible, and that one can find F which do not satisfy the inequality because of getting several pairs of elements to have the same union.  Gerhard "Back To The Drawing Board" Paseman, 2011.09.16

Comment: But, intuiutively, it seems to me that the best way to get most overlap in the unions is to start off by "packing" the sets as close as you can, i.e: as k-subsets of an n-set. Not that this proves anything :)

Comment: I sympathize with the intuition. So instead let's consider k-sets of N >> n.  Perhaps it can be shown that there is a partition of [k,N] into intervals [k_i, k_{i+1}) such that C(N,k+i) is less than the sets of < F > whose sizes fall into the ith interval, and that the inequality can be established that way.  It would be interesting to know this even in the case N=n+1.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.09.17

Comment: Yes, even the case N = n+1 seems non-trivial. The only actual "result" I have on this problem is the case k=2 (the inequality, not the uniqueness). For k = 1 it's trivial. I tried the same approach for k=3, but it becomes a mess, a new idea is needed. One other comment is perhaps worth making : In Reimer's paper he begins by "up-shifting" a union-closed family - crucially, this preserves union-closure. But when you've got generating sets of a fixed size k, it seems you'd want to "side-shift" instead (this is a well-known operation). But this does not preserve union-closure. 

Comment: That reminds me of some unpublished work I did for unions of 2-sets.  There are two authors who come to mind, if only I could remember the details.  One is E. Knill, who also had some 2-set results.  The other is a coworker of Theresa Vaughn, (I think Robert Johnson or Morris?), who had some 3-set results.  This is all in connection with Frankl's conjecture of course.  Gerhard "Ask Me About System Design" Paseman, 2011.10.04

Comment: A sort of dual of Reimer's result can be found here: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1709.05539v2.pdf  Is it relevant?